# Register SQL-table in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

If I have a PostgresDB that contains both Django models and other SQL tables, is it possible to register these other SQL tables in the Django admin panel?

More details about the setup:
I have a docker-compose setup where Django is running in one container, a Postgres DB in another, and a slack-app in a third container. Django is connected to the DB and the models are registered in the admin panel. This works as intended. The slack-app is also connected to the same DB and has some tables there that are not Django-models. I would like to also access these through the Django admin panel in order to have everything in one place. Is this possible?

Comment: You can make unmanaged models and register these as Django modeladmin's: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define *unmanaged* models in Django. These models will *not* construct migrations, but will only query the database to select, insert, etc.

Django offers a tool [**`inspectdb`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) to inspect the database and write the corresponding unamanged models. You thus can use this with:

```
python3 manage.py inspectdb table1 table2 tablen
```

It will then write the corresponding models for these tables to the standard output channel, and you thus can copy these in the `models.py`. In the `Meta` of these models it will add a `managed = False` to denote that Django will not migrate these models.

Once you registered these models, you can register a `ModelAdmin` with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app_name.models import Model1, Model2, Modeln

admin.site.register(Model1)
admin.site.register(Model2)
admin.site.register(Modeln)
```